# Copy and paste from 1 excel workbook to another and add two more fields

Tags: excel, vba

say I have data in columns C-F and I need to copy this data into another book with the same columns (C-F) in the destination workbook, I also need to add two more fields of data contained in the source sheet say A2 and B2, I am very new so apologies if I sound vague, I’ve been using an adapted version of the below code for another project, how can I add to this? Thank you for reading

```
Sub MoveRowsToTireCases()
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Set the source and target sheets
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cases")
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tire Cases")
    
    ' Find the last row in the source sheet
    lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each row in the source sheet
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        ' Check if cell in column X contains "TIRES"
        If sourceSheet.Cells(i, "X").Value = "TIRES" Then
            ' Copy the entire row to the target sheet
            sourceSheet.Rows(i).Copy    Destination:=targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            ' Delete the row from the source sheet
            sourceSheet.Rows(i).Delete
            ' Decrement the loop counter as the rows are shifting up
            i = i - 1
            ' Update the last row value
            lastRow = lastRow - 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you should change the tag `vb.net` to `vba`? I'm also confused, since you are copying the entire row, but the problem statement says you want to copy only columns C-F, and then the cells in A2 and B2?

Comment: Sorry I’m a new member, say I’m looking to copy a row in columns c-f to a destination sheet based on a value, but add someone’s name contained in A2 and todays date in B2 to each of those rows in the destination sheet?

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted specific data in specific cells in a specific worksheet, I would do something like this, with some changes to the other code:

```vb
' Loop through each row in the source sheet
Dim targetRowCount = 2 'Initial row; this will overwrite anything in the cells
For i = 2 To lastRow
    ' Check if cell in column X contains "TIRES"
    If InStr(sourceSheet.Cells(i, "X").Value, "TIRES") > 0 Then
        ' Copy the cells needed to the target sheet
        targetSheet.Cells(targetRowCount, 3) = sourceSheet.Cells(i, 3)
        targetSheet.Cells(targetRowCount, 4) = sourceSheet.Cells(i, 4)
        targetSheet.Cells(targetRowCount, 5) = sourceSheet.Cells(i, 5)
        targetSheet.Cells(targetRowCount, 1) = sourceSheet.Cells(1, 2)
        targetSheet.Cells(targetRowCount, 2) = sourceSheet.Cells(2, 2)
        targetRowCount = targetRowCount + 1
        ' Delete the row from the source sheet
        sourceSheet.Rows(i).Delete
        ' Decrement the loop counter as the rows are shifting up
        i = i - 1
        ' Update the last row value
        lastRow = lastRow - 1
    End If
Next i
```

I hope this is what you're looking for. I'm not certain of the specifications for A2 and B2, which this always takes from the same location instead of the currently processing row. I'm also putting in the `InStr` because the comment says "contains".

Comment: Thank you for answering I will give this a try